# How do we do dblapi for webhooks?

Tags: discord.js

I need help on binding webhooks from dblapi to my bot. I follow the api docs on its official api site but it won't work.
Code:

```js
const dbl = new DBL(yourDBLTokenHere, { webhookPort: 5000, webhookAuth: 'password' });
dbl.webhook.on('ready', hook => {
  console.log(`Webhook running at http://${hook.hostname}:${hook.port}${hook.path}`);
});
```

It says port 5000 is already in use, I had tried other ports too it came with the same problem. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Well maybe some other app is listening on port 5000. Have you tried identifying it with a netstat ?

Comment: What is the netstat?

Comment: https://linux.die.net/man/8/netstat

Comment: I don't get it. Is there another way?

Comment: Can you give me a template using netstat?

Comment: I don't think you understand. The error is that there is already an other server or app listening on the same port (5000). netstat is a tool that may help you identify it if you don't know what it could be.

Comment: Is there a template of it

Comment: I figure it out! I was sharding so my first shard has the port